# Parse a string in each row and expand the results into a tidy dataframe

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I have a dataframe like:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
     id text_1                                              text_2                                                          
  <int> <chr>                                               <chr>                                                           
1     1 "{1=>{:name=>\"aaa\", :priority=>0, :count=>4}, 7=… "{:name=>\"bbb\", :priority=>0,  :count=>4}, {:name=>\"ddd\", :…
2     2 "{1=>{:name=>\"aaa\", :priority=>0, :count=>5}, 3=… "{:name=>\"bbb\", :priority=>0,  :count=>4}, {:name=>\"ccc\", :…
```

Reproducible:

```
structure(list(id = 1:2, text_1 = c("{1=>{:name=>\"aaa\", :priority=>0, :count=>4}, 7=>{:name=>\"bbb\", :priority=>0, :count=>2}}", 
"{1=>{:name=>\"aaa\", :priority=>0, :count=>5}, 3=>{:name=>\"ccc\", :priority=>0, :count=>3}}"
), text_2 = c("{:name=>\"bbb\", :priority=>0,  :count=>4}, {:name=>\"ddd\", :priority=>0, :count=>2}", 
"{:name=>\"bbb\", :priority=>0,  :count=>4}, {:name=>\"ccc\", :priority=>0, :count=>2}, {:name=>\"ddd\", :priority=>0, :count=>9}"
)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), spec = structure(list(cols = list(id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), text_1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), text_2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector"))), class = "col_spec"))
```

where each row contain a string to be parsed.

The first column contains fields with an identifier, in the second the fields are just between a set of parantheses.

I would like to unfold it reaching this result, in a way that the product that are not in common at the `id` level are set to zero.

There is a closed number of product, so it will need to be filled with all the combinations.

```
# A tibble: 14 x 5
      id product priority count level 
   <int> <chr>      <int> <int> <chr> 
 1     1 aaa            0     4 text_1
 2     1 bbb            0     4 text_1
 3     1 ccc            0     0 text_1
 4     2 aaa            0     5 text_1
 5     2 bbb            0     0 text_1
 6     2 ccc            0     3 text_1
 7     1 aaa            0     0 text_2
 8     1 bbb            0     4 text_2
 9     1 ccc            0     0 text_2
10     1 ddd            0     2 text_2
11     2 aaa            0     0 text_2
12     2 bbb            0     4 text_2
13     2 ccc            0     2 text_2
14     2 ddd            0     9 text_2
```

I think I have to use some sort of combination of `extract` but I am lost.

Comment: Where did the data come from? I ask because it looks like it was originally JSON, which you can process using R.

Comment: unfortunately it is not a json but a very messy messy log from a script to be parsed.

Answer (score 3):

If it is originally JSON, as @neilfws suggested - it would be easier to parse with something like the `jsonlite` package. If not, try below:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  gather(level, 'val', text_1, text_2) %>%
  separate(val, into = paste0('val', 1:(max(str_count(.$val,"\\},"))+1)), "\\},") %>%
  gather(val, ugly_text, starts_with('val')) %>%
  select(-val) %>%
  filter(!is.na(ugly_text)) %>%
  mutate(product = str_match(ugly_text, ':name=>\\"(.*?)\\"')[, 2],
         priority = str_match(ugly_text , ':priority=>([0-9])')[, 2],
         count = str_match(ugly_text , ':count=>([0-9])')[, 2]) %>%
  select(id, product, priority, count, level) %>%
  full_join(distinct(expand.grid(id = .$id, product = .$product, level = .$level)),
            by = c('id', 'product', 'level')) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(priority, count), ~if_else(is.na(.x), 0, as.numeric(.x))) %>%
  arrange(level, id, product)

# A tibble: 16 x 5
      id product priority count level 
   <int> <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
 1     1 aaa            0     4 text_1
 2     1 bbb            0     2 text_1
 3     1 ccc            0     0 text_1
 4     1 ddd            0     0 text_1
 5     2 aaa            0     5 text_1
 6     2 bbb            0     0 text_1
 7     2 ccc            0     3 text_1
 8     2 ddd            0     0 text_1
 9     1 aaa            0     0 text_2
10     1 bbb            0     4 text_2
11     1 ccc            0     0 text_2
12     1 ddd            0     2 text_2
13     2 aaa            0     0 text_2
14     2 bbb            0     4 text_2
15     2 ccc            0     2 text_2
16     2 ddd            0     9 text_2
```

I'm not exactly sure what you meant when you wrote "There is a closed number of product, so it will need to be filled with all the combinations"  - but this should at least be a start.

Comment: Hey, I really don't understand how ':name=>\\"([A-Za-z]{3})')[, 2]' works... if the variable "name" has more than 3 characters (and the string may vary), I am not sure the regex will work. it would be something that catches everything between 'name =>" ' and ' " '.. @zack

Comment: regarding the "closed number" it means that in this case the unique products will be "aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd" but they don't appear for every id, level. I would like to fill out the missing ones for each id, level combination with name + value set to zero as in row 3 in my example output. @zack

Comment: for the matching group, you could always do a non-greedy capture with `+?` instead of `{3}` for variable length products. For your missing level combinations, that seems a reasonable candidate for a cross-join using `expand.grid` or something like that. Happy to review this tomorrow when I've a bit more time.

Comment: thanks! `expand.grid` is what I am looking for. The regex doesn't work tho: I tried `product = str_match(ugly_text, ':name=>\\"([A-Za-z]+?)')[, 2]` and for a string like `:name=>"vincent 121"`, it doesn't seem to catch the sub-string `vincent 121` @zack

Comment: interesting - I've updated the code to both account for the non present combinations and the more broadly scoped product names (it should now capture anything between the `\"` character combinations).

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt to clean the dataset using the `tidyverse` package. It is not the same as your desired output. This is because your output include some combination like `ccc` or `ddd` in some of the group. However, I cannot figure out the rules, such as why `text_2` has `aaa`, but `text_1` has no `ddd`. So I decided to keep my answer as is unless there are new information.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat2 <- dat %>%
    gather(level, text, starts_with("text_")) %>%
    separate_rows(text, sep = ", ") %>%
    mutate(text = map(text, ~str_split(.x, pattern = "=>"))) %>%
    mutate(text = map(text, function(x){
       len <- length(x[[1]])
       y <- x[[1]][c(len - 1, len)]
       return(y)
    })) %>%
    mutate(text = map(text, ~str_replace_all(.x, "[:punct:]", ""))) %>%
    mutate(Column = map_chr(text, 1), Value = map_chr(text, 2)) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(Column, Value), funs(str_trim(.))) %>%
    select(-text) %>%
    mutate(Group = cumsum(Column %in% "name")) %>% 
    spread(Column, Value) %>%
    select(id, product = name, priority, count, level) %>%
    arrange(level, id, product) 
dat2
# # A tibble: 9 x 5
#      id product priority count level 
#   <int> <chr>   <chr>    <chr> <chr> 
# 1     1 aaa     0        4     text_1
# 2     1 bbb     0        2     text_1
# 3     2 aaa     0        5     text_1
# 4     2 ccc     0        3     text_1
# 5     1 bbb     0        4     text_2
# 6     1 ddd     0        2     text_2
# 7     2 bbb     0        4     text_2
# 8     2 ccc     0        2     text_2
# 9     2 ddd     0        9     text_2
```

I have tried to add a `complete` call to expand the data frame with all combination. But now the output has more rows than your desired output because `ddd` are now with `text_1`. Again, it is not clear what is your rule to create the desired output.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat2 <- dat %>%
    gather(level, text, starts_with("text_")) %>%
    separate_rows(text, sep = ", ") %>%
    mutate(text = map(text, ~str_split(.x, pattern = "=>"))) %>%
    mutate(text = map(text, function(x){
       len <- length(x[[1]])
       y <- x[[1]][c(len - 1, len)]
       return(y)
    })) %>%
    mutate(text = map(text, ~str_replace_all(.x, "[:punct:]", ""))) %>%
    mutate(Column = map_chr(text, 1), Value = map_chr(text, 2)) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(Column, Value), funs(str_trim(.))) %>%
    select(-text) %>%
    mutate(Group = cumsum(Column %in% "name")) %>% 
    spread(Column, Value) %>%
    complete(name, id, level, fill = list(priority = 0, count = 0)) %>%
    select(id, product = name, priority, count, level) %>%
    arrange(level, id, product) 
dat2
# # A tibble: 16 x 5
#      id product priority count level 
#   <int> <chr>   <chr>    <chr> <chr> 
# 1     1 aaa     0        4     text_1
# 2     1 bbb     0        2     text_1
# 3     1 ccc     0        0     text_1
# 4     1 ddd     0        0     text_1
# 5     2 aaa     0        5     text_1
# 6     2 bbb     0        0     text_1
# 7     2 ccc     0        3     text_1
# 8     2 ddd     0        0     text_1
# 9     1 aaa     0        0     text_2
#10     1 bbb     0        4     text_2
#11     1 ccc     0        0     text_2
#12     1 ddd     0        2     text_2
#13     2 aaa     0        0     text_2
#14     2 bbb     0        4     text_2
#15     2 ccc     0        2     text_2
#16     2 ddd     0        9     text_2
```